# MySQL Select query returning wrong rows

Tags: mysql

I want to filter my table for a specific value. There should always the next lower value be shown.

```
+----+-----------+-------+------------+
| id | productid | lvl   | value      |
+----+-----------+-------+------------+
|  2 | 7         | 10    | 100        |
|  3 | 7         | 5     | 50         |
|  6 | 7         | 1     | 25         |
+----+-----------+--
```

If i search for lvl 6, there should be level 5 be outputted. If i search for level 14, there should be lvl 10 outputted.

Have tryed the following queries, but none of them are working as i want. As example this query works for values over 4. If i use a value under 4, i would need to change desc to asc to get the right result:

```
SELECT * FROM `levels` where lvl <= '6' ORDER BY lvl desc limit 1
```

Whats the correct way to get returned the next lower (or equaled) row with a sql query?

Comment: What you are doing is previous max and what is the data type of lvl ?

Comment: What should be the output for  `lvl <= 4`?

Comment: if the `lvl` field is a VARCHAR or CHAR data type, you'll need to CAST it to numeric for ordering and probably the comparison as well.

Comment: The field is a text field. Should i change it to numeric?
@peterm Output of lvl <= 4 should be lvl = 1

Comment: @Alde If you have the access to do so, and have no reason to think you would need non-numeric data in the field, I would strongly encourage doing so. Integer datatypes are much faster, and generally more compact as well.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your query. it works fine:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e567f/1

```
SELECT * FROM `levels` where lvl <= 6 ORDER BY lvl desc limit 1;

SELECT * FROM `levels` where lvl <= 14 ORDER BY lvl desc limit 1;

SELECT * FROM `levels_char` where lvl <= '6' ORDER BY lvl desc limit 1;

SELECT * FROM `levels_char` where lvl <= '14' ORDER BY lvl desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Please try with lvl = 10 or lvl <= 11 - this should return row with lvl 10, but return lvl 5.